# Find a unique locator Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a unique locator of the "update profile picture button" in my Facebook account to use it for automation test (selenium webdriver with java).

I use `driver.findElement(By.className("_156p")).click();`, but it doesn't work.

What should I use?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Being unable to see the rest of the html source, I can't say for sure, but my guess is that the class is actually defined earlier in the source. The problem with using just a class name is that class names do not have to be unique on a page. The unique version of a class name is id, and if you are testing code that you can edit, try to use lots of ids.

If that's not the case, a decent way to deal with code that you can'y edit yourself is to use a css selector. Really good information on doing them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Another good debugging option is to use javascript or python to run a webdriver from the terminal. Because these languages are not compiled, you can run them in real time, which can allow you to tweak a class name a lot quicker. If you don't have experience with python, check [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) out. By using python/javascript you can create the webdriver, and then keep typing in `driver.find_element_by_whatever("value_to_find")` while on the same page. This will be much quicker than running the java program from scratch for every different "value_to_find".

Answer (score 0):

As the page source you have provided is pretty limited unable to come up with a stable locator. How about getting the div using the text through xpath.

```
"//div[.='Update Profile Picture']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("_156n"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Worked for me.